# \makeglossaries conflict with indexing

Tags: indexing, glossaries, acronyms

This is my first post to ask for help since I cannot find any solution. I use MacTex.
I am using glossaries pkg to generate list of acronyms, symbols and glossary of terms. I want to include also an index, however, the instruction `\makeglossaries` won't let any index to be generated. 
When I omit `\makeglossaries` and `\gls{whatever}` from the code (and delete the temp files) the index is generated, but of course not everything else related to glossaries. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[
acronym,
toc,
shortcuts,
]{glossaries}
\glsaddall

%\makeglossaries
\makeindex


\begin{document}
\newacronym{iex}{IEX}{Ion Exchange Chromatography}

Some dumb text\index{test} and %\gls{iex} and again \gls{iex}

\printindex
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]


\end{document}
```

Could somebody please explain me what am I doing wrong, the conflict here or what can I do to avoid it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I remove the comment characters and compile, I have no problem in getting both the index and the list of acronyms. What are the steps you're following for the production of the complete document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are making a mistake in the way you are trying to compile your index and glossary.

If you run the following sequence of commands you should have both your index and glossary in your compiled document (supposing that `myfile.tex` is the name of your document):

> pdflatex myfile
>
> makeindex myfile
>
> makeindex.exe -s myfile.ist -t myfile.alg -o myfile.acr myfile.acn
>
> pdflatex myfile
>
> pdflatex myfile

If you have Perl installed, you can replace the third command with

> makeglossaries myfile

Comment: Apparently the problem was the software (Texpad). I had never need to generate glossaries and index and therefore I had never encountered this problem. I tried other compilers available for mac and indeed both the glossaries and the index were generated. I will write to the developers so they can take a look.

Comment: @egreg: I followed the same order as stated in the answer but I guess some glitch in the software didn't allow to generate everything correctly. I am using another compiler for the time being and everything runs smoothly.